# On the definition of Markov Processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Often the following definition of a Markov Process is given:

Suppose $\{X_{t}\}$ is a stochastic process defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Then $\{X_{t}\}$ is a Markov process iff for all bounded measurable functions $f$ we have:

$$\mathbb{E}[f(X_{t + s}) \mid \sigma\{X_{u} \vert u \leq t\}] = \mathbb{E}[f(X_{t+s}) \mid X_{t}].$$

It is often explained that this intuitively means that predicting the future is independent of the past, once we know the current value of the process. What I do not understand is why can't we just impose

$$\mathbb{E}[X_{t + s} \mid \sigma\{X_{u} \vert u \leq t\}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{t+s} \mid X_{t}],$$

which seems to be a more natural definition (assuming these expectations exist).

Comment: Because this defines a different class of processes and we are interested in the first class. To get a grasp of the difference, assume for example that $$X_{t+1}=X_t+Z_tX_{t-1}$$ where $(Z_t)$ is i.i.d. and centered.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!